# A UIButton is pressed in 1 VC and I need it to save the buttons title to a label in a different view controller not directly segued to each other

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, xcode7, viewcontroller

In the initial set up of my app I need the user to chose a genre type. i have it set up such that the user selects from a list of UIButtons which are all different genre types. I need this genre selection to save to the users profile. The next view controller is the same set up as the genreVC but asking for instrument instead of genre. The next segue from here is to view controller 3 the usersVC profile and it should have saved which two buttons were selected on the previous two VC's by updating a label. I have tagged each button with a number and have tried next to everything.

How do I save which button has been pressed on a different view controller to the users profile and update the label on the users profile to the name of the button pressed?

I am using each button individually and have them tagged as such as seen here:

```
    @IBAction func popGenreButton(sender: UIButton) {
    if(sender.tag == 6){
        print("Pop genre selected")
    }
}

@IBAction func altGenreButton(sender: UIButton) {
    if(sender.tag == 7){
        print("Alternative genre selected")
    }
}

@IBAction func electronicGenreButton(sender: UIButton) {
    if(sender.tag == 8){
        print("Electronic genre selected")
    }
}
```

I also tried adding each button into genreSelection as shown below that didn't work so I stuck with the individual buttons above.

```
 @IBAction func genreSelectionButton(sender: UIButton) {

   print(sender.titleLabel!.text!)
genreResult.text = genreString + " genre has been saved to your profile"
    }
```

I also created a nib with myModalDelegate and protocol and nope.

I thought maybe I could create a genre array and when a certain button is selected it calls a certain item from the array and updates that item to the label but I was unsure how to go about this too.

I am using Xcode 7 and Swift 2.0 and Parse as my cloud server.

As you can see I have a lot to learn yet with Swift. I have been searching how to do this for the past week and can't figure it out. I am a 'lot' out of my depth but want to figure it out, if anyone can help that would be great!

Comment: show the code of how you are moving between view controllers

Comment: It is just with the use of button and segue this is the segue from GenreVC to InstrumentVC                                                                                 IBAction func nextInstrument(sender: AnyObject) {
   self.performSegueWithIdentifier("nextInstrumentSegue", sender:self)
    }                                                                                                                this is the segue from InstrumentVC to UserProfileVC                      IBAction func letsGo(sender: AnyObject) {
     self.performSegueWithIdentifier("letsGoSegue", sender:self)
    }

Comment: if you are using segues, better use delegates. Look into http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_delegates.htm

Comment: Ya I tried delegates as well and I could only get it to work for updating the VC directly after not one that is 2 clicks away. I have no obj c experience but I'll have a read of that article and see if it helps my earlier research, thanks Mr.T.

Comment: why dont you store the value in a global (not so nice) or use the coredata  to store it in db (cleaner)? for anything that is more than the next or previous controller away, this seems less brittle since u can then move the 3rd VC anywhere in the stack heirarchy and this would still work.

Comment: Hi Apple and Oranges yup I created a global store for it as suggested by yourself and Animal below. Thanks! I will defo look at trying coredata later on. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution would be something like creating a global store for those values

i.e.

```
struct Choices {
    static var genre: String?
    static var instruments: String?
}
```

then you could in your different view controllers write and read from it by simply

```
Choices.instrument =  "trumpet"
```

or

```
label.text = Choices.genre
```

A prettier solution would be to create a similar class as the previous struct but not have the variables static. You could then pass it along and fill up with the values from each VC and use the values in the last VC where you are setting the label text